# How can I get the latest timestamp from a list that is before current date?

Tags: select, google-bigquery, max

I have a table with dated conversions rates. The startdate are both in the past and the future. What I want to do is to find the latest startdate that is before today.

I have tried to use MAX(DatedConversionRate.startdate) to fetch the latest date possible, and I tried to use a WHERE statement that find the latest day before today `DatedConversionRate_Start_date`< CURRENT_TIMESTAMP().

This is what I have tested, but it can't recognize the `DatedConversionRate_Max_Start_date` field:

```
SELECT
  Opportunity.id,
  Opportunity.currencyisocode,
  MAX(DatedConversionRate.startdate) AS `DatedConversionRate_Max_Start_date`,
  DatedConversionRate.conversionrate AS `DatedConversionRate_Conversion_rate`,
  DatedConversionRate.isocode AS `DatedConversionRate_Iso_code`
FROM
  `dataset.Opportunity` Opportunity
LEFT JOIN 
  `dataset.DatedConversionRate` DatedConversionRate 
  ON DatedConversionRate.isocode = Opportunity.currencyisocode
WHERE
  `DatedConversionRate_Max_Start_date` = `DatedConversionRate_Start_date`
  AND `DatedConversionRate_Start_date`< CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You declared the names of the columns in the SELECT statement, it will return an error if you use these names in your following WHERE statement.

Did you try this:

```html
SELECT
  Opportunity.id,
  Opportunity.currencyisocode,
  MAX(DatedConversionRate.startdate) AS `DatedConversionRate_Max_Start_date`,
  DatedConversionRate.conversionrate AS `DatedConversionRate_Conversion_rate`,
  DatedConversionRate.isocode AS `DatedConversionRate_Iso_code`
FROM
  `dataset.Opportunity` Opportunity
LEFT JOIN 
  `dataset.DatedConversionRate` DatedConversionRate 
  ON DatedConversionRate.isocode = Opportunity.currencyisocode
WHERE
  MAX(DatedConversionRate.startdate) = `DatedConversionRate_Start_date`
  AND MAX(DatedConversionRate.startdate) < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
```